# Sending data from a class to an activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Have a question about sending data between classes and activities.

I currently have a class that monitors outgoing class and gets the number of an outgoing call.

I instantiate this class in my main `Activity` and run its method that retrieves the number.

However I now have another `Activity` that I want to pass the number to.

I start this `Activity` through an `Intent` from the class that gets the number.

So it works like this:

> MainActiviy Starts > Starts Object that listens for outgoing call >
>   outgoing call detected > Object gets outgoing number > object fires
>   Intent to create new Activity after outgoing call logged and number
>   retrieved > new Activity displays

I hope that is a bit clearer?

So I want to send the number from the class (object) to the new `Activity` that it has started.

So what is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Is there anyway to do the reverse? send the data from a service to a class (object) that is not an activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `putExtra()` on the `Intent` you are using with `startService()`. Use `putExtra()` to store the phone number in the `Intent`. Use `getExtra()` in the service being started to retrieve the phone number.

Comment: Thanks, I actually have it done, typically enough I was loking up the wrong ideas and eventually stumbled across it, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Pass the number as an extra: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable[])

Comment: Thanks :) actually came across it myself after looking up the wrong things!

Answer (score 0):

For a different approach without bundling your data to the intent, you can try the GNLauncher component of the following library I wrote to make this taks simpler when there is a number of objects to be passed in and with different objectives. https://github.com/noxiouswinter/gnlib_android/wiki#gnlauncher